# Is $\mathbb{N}$ a complete metric space with this metric $d(a,b) = \sqrt{1-2\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a+b}}$?

Tags: metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Is $X:=\mathbb{N}$ a complete metric space with this metric $d(a,b) = \sqrt{1-2\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a+b}}$?

Thanks for your help!

**Edit**:
This metric plays a role in the formulation of the abc-conjecture:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352054/the-abc-conjecture-as-an-inequality-for-inner-products

Comment: There is a misconception here from the start: a bounded and complete metric space is not necessarily compact. Take $\mathbb N$ with the discrete metric, for instance.

Comment: you are right, i confused "totally bounded" with "bounded"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a\ne b$, then letting
\begin{align*}
a_1&=\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}\\
b_1&=\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}\\
\end{align*}
we have
$$
\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a+b}
=
\frac{1}{a_1+b_1}
\le
\frac{1}{3}
$$
so $d(a,b) \ge \sqrt{1-2{\,\cdot\,}\frac{1}{3}}={\large{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}}$.

It follows that every Cauchy sequence must be eventually constant, hence convergent.

Therefore $X$ is complete.

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: Uau, I newer saw this metric. Is it usefull?

Comment: @Aqua: I have no idea whether it's useful in general, but in any case, I just _used_ it!

Comment: @Aqua: This metric plays a role in the formulation of the abc-conjecture: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352054/the-abc-conjecture-as-an-inequality-for-inner-products