# Is $\mathbb{N}$ a totally bounded metric space with this metric $d(a,b) = \sqrt{1-2\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a+b}}$?

Tags: number-theory, metric-spaces, compactness

Is $X:=\mathbb{N}$ a totally bounded ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space#Definition_for_a_metric_space ) metric space with this metric $d(a,b) = \sqrt{1-2\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a+b}}$?

This metric plays a role in the formulation of the abc-conjecture:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352054/the-abc-conjecture-as-an-inequality-for-inner-products

(It was shown by @quasi here ( [Is $\mathbb{N}$ a complete metric space with this metric $d(a,b) = \sqrt{1-2\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a+b}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621666/is-mathbbn-a-complete-metric-space-with-this-metric-da-b-sqrt1-2-fra)) that this metric space is complete. If it was totally bounded, then it would be compact.)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A (unrelated) curiosity that I don't know (to this date my topology is bad) and that I was thinking is if it is known or it can to deduce easily if some of your metrics from your posts have the property that $\mathbb{N}$ **has approximate midpoints** (see the Wikipedia *Intrinsic metric*). I hope don't disturb with this commment and isn't required a response of this comment, really I don't know if it makes sense for the metrics that you are studying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the referenced answer,

$\;\;\;$[Is $\mathbb{N}$ a complete metric space with this metric $d(a,b) = \sqrt{1-2\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a+b}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621666)

if $a\ne b$, then $d(a,b) \ge {\large{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}}$, hence for any $\epsilon\in (0, {\large{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}}]$, an open ball of radius $\epsilon$ is a singleton.

It follows that $X$ is not totally bounded.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifying answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $\{2^n\}_n$. For distinct $n$ and $m$ we have $d(2^n, 2^m)\geq 1/\sqrt{3}$ so $\mathbb{N}$ can’t be covered with finitely many $1/(2\sqrt{3})$ balls because each such ball contains at most one point in out sequence.

Comment: thanks for your answer.